# Dynamic distribution lists in exchange 2010

Tags: dynamic, exchange-server, distribution-list

I have been creating a number of dynamic distribution list for groups and group leaders.

Each of our groups has a "user" created in AD that is used as a contact that can be searched for in Outlook and other Ldap applications. All of these users have a last name of "department", so I can create a dynamic distribution list based on this property and the list will contain the group email address for all the groups.

But I also want to make a list of all managers of the groups. so it needs to be a query that says some thing like

"If user appears in manager field of any user that has "Department" as their last name, then add them to a group.

Is this possible with a recipient filter query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use base filters in Dynamic Distribution lists as long as you build it via powershell.  Refer to this older serverfault answer.

https://serverfault.com/questions/246391/how-do-i-make-a-ldap-query-based-dynamic-distribution-group-in-exchange-2010

OR build your query via AD Advanced search or ldp, then you can use true LDAP queries!  Refer to this which bypasses the inability to add direct LDAP queries for Dynamic Lists:  https://smtpport25.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/exchange-20072010-dynamic-distribution-list-customizing/

Comment: Hi, I will look in to this, just a question are both thoses URL's meant to be the same?

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry bout that.  The existing Exchange "filters" are ok to use, still recommend powershell, but when they removed just using LDAP, that angered a lot of people because it removed non-Exchange fields from being used.  The second link gives examples of how to bypass that.... you can still create a list, create an ldap query, then added to the list via ADSI... horrible but even Microsoft Premier suggested I do i that way when I complained to them about the feature removal.

Comment: OK so I have a filter for get-adusers. Get-ADUser -filter {employeetype -like "*Group*"} -Properties * | select Manager}. which returns all the mangers for users with a employeetype value  "Group". But I cant see how to put this in to a dynamic distribution list.

Comment: You have two choices.... convert to OPATH: http://blogs.technet.com/b/ilvancri/archive/2010/06/15/don-t-forget-to-update-your-ldap-filters-to-opath-filters-when-transitioning-from-exchange-2003-to-exchange-2010.aspx

Or, use ADSI to find the Legacy LDAP field in the Dynamic Dist list container object and directly add the filter there.  It's not supported but I found OPATH to not include all my needed fields.

Comment: we run exchange 2010 so I assume OPATH is already what we are using?   So other dynamic list I have created are working fine. But the general filter is "find users in goup X" or find users with attribue X and path Y..." In the case above its the  pipe to select that does not seem to work.

Comment: so "set-dynamicgroup -identy Groupleaders - recipentfilter (employeetype ieq "Group"} works fine. and return all the users expected, but I cant do the "| select manager" which would return the manages of the users not the users them selves. I think its going to have to be a scheduled task to update the group rather than a dynamic group

Comment: I decided on an easier way, rather than play with the distribution list I simple set it up to filter on a currently unused attribute (customeattribute 13) and the power shell populates this. In this way all the dynamic lists are straight forward so teaching others how to set them up is easy. and the script just tags on to current "housekeeping" script in AD that keeps all up to date.